# Creating Custom Filters for list_filter in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to make custom filters for django admin instead of the normal 'is_staff' and 'is_superuser'. I have read this [list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) in Django docs. 
Custom Filters work in this way:

```
from datetime import date

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class DecadeBornListFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
    # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.
    title = _('decade born')

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
    parameter_name = 'decade'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        """
        Returns a list of tuples. The first element in each
        tuple is the coded value for the option that will
        appear in the URL query. The second element is the
        human-readable name for the option that will appear
        in the right sidebar.
        """
        return (
            ('80s', _('in the eighties')),
            ('90s', _('in the nineties')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        """
        Returns the filtered queryset based on the value
        provided in the query string and retrievable via
        `self.value()`.
        """
        # Compare the requested value (either '80s' or '90s')
        # to decide how to filter the queryset.
        if self.value() == '80s':
            return queryset.filter(birthday__gte=date(1980, 1, 1),
                                    birthday__lte=date(1989, 12, 31))
        if self.value() == '90s':
            return queryset.filter(birthday__gte=date(1990, 1, 1),
                                    birthday__lte=date(1999, 12, 31))

class PersonAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (DecadeBornListFilter,)
```

But i have already made custom functions for list_display like this:

```
def Student_Country(self, obj):
    return '%s' % obj.country
Student_Country.short_description = 'Student-Country'
```

Is it possible i could use the custom functions for list_display in list_filter instead of writing a new custom function for list_filter? Any suggestions or improvements are welcome.. Need some guidance on this... Thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215751/can-i-make-list-filter-in-django-admin-to-only-show-referenced-foreignkeys

Comment: for others visiting this question, I found this simple answer helpful: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/filtering_calculated_fields.html

Answer (score 88):

You can indeed add custom filters to admin filters by extending SimpleListFilter. For instance, if you want to add a continent filter for 'Africa' to the country admin filter used above, you can do the following:

In admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class CountryFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'country' # or use _('country') for translated title
    parameter_name = 'country'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        countries = set([c.country for c in model_admin.model.objects.all()])
        return [(c.id, c.name) for c in countries] + [
          ('AFRICA', 'AFRICA - ALL')]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 'AFRICA':
            return queryset.filter(country__continent='Africa')
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(country__id__exact=self.value())

class CityAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (CountryFilter,)
```

Comment: in queryset it is missing the default all selection: if self.value() is None: return queryset.all()

Comment: The values in the `lookups` method get coerced into strings so make sure your control flow in the`queryset` method checks for string values and not something else like integer or boolean fields.

Comment: It's a good idea to use `.distinct()` instead of set

Comment: How can i remove  "All" option from filter

Answer (score 10):

Your `list_display` ,method returns a string, but if I understand correctly, what you want to do is add a filter which allows selection of countries of students, correct?

For this simple relation filter, and in fact for the "Student-Country" list display column as well, you don't need to create a custom filter class, nor a custom list display method; this would suffice:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('country', )
    list_filter = ('country', )
```

The way django does `list_filter`, as explained [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), is first by automatically matching fields you provide to pre-built filter classes; these filters include CharField and ForeignKey.

`list_display` similarly automates the population of the changelist column using the field passed by retrieving the related objects and returning the **unicode** value of these (same as in the method you provided above).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Rick Westera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45136544/6014063) answer, here is the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) for this situation

> **`ModelAdmin.list_filter`**
>   Set `list_filter` to activate filters in the right sidebar of the change list page of the admin
>   `list_filter` should be a list or tuple of elements

Comment: Hi hasher, I added a basic summary of the link you provided. Link only answers are frowned upon and tend to be deleted, as links can die, change, etc. Answers should be self-contained with the link working as further info.

Answer (score 3):

the `lookup` function is that show the exists values in admin;
in `queryset` function, `self.value()` is that was filtering by..

```
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class AllPriceFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

    title = 'All Price'
    parameter_name = 'All Price'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return [(i.all_price, i.all_price) for i in model_admin.model.objects.all()]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(all_price__lte=self.value())


class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (AllPriceFilter, )
```