# django model display and search

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in django
models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Author(models.Model):
    books = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    search_fields=['author_name']

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    list_display=['book_id', 'title', 'get_author']
    search_fields = ['title', 'book_id']
    def get_author(self, obj):
    names = [a.author_name for a in obj.author_set.all()]
    return names
```

Is there any other way to display the list of authors in book admin page. As this result is giving output in unicode 
Author name
[u'Zev Halevi']
[u'Kathryn Worth', u'Dorothy Bayley']

Also i need to provide a seperate search bar for searching through the authors. I am not able to use the author_name column as this is a foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
def get_author(self, obj):
    names = "\n".join([a.author_name for a in obj.author_set.all()])
return names
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now i have search fields for the books and titles. But how can i add seperate searching in the name of authors.

Comment: Check this question it's similar to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522661/how-to-override-the-queryset-giving-the-filters-in-list-filter