# Hiding the one certain row of tables in admin

Tags: python, django

I want to hiding the one certain row of tables in admin.

I have these tables.

```
id name
1  main // hide this row in admin.
2  John
3  Lisa
```

At first, I try to override template `change_list_result.html` and edit here, but still no success.

```
<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
{% for item in result %}
{{ item }}{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Is there any good way or my plan is basically ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is probably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522661/how-to-override-the-queryset-giving-the-filters-in-list-filter) : overriding the admin class `get_queryset()` method.

```py
def get_queryset(self, request): 
   qs = super(IssueAdmin, self).get_queryset(request) 
   return qs.filter(myparam=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, I can override the `get_queryset` function of admin class     `def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(IssueAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(myparam=False)`