# Overriding django model admin's queryset trouble

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model like this:

```
class JobAttachment(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='attachment')
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='images')
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=225,null = True,blank = True)
    spam_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I in my model admin have overrided model admin's queryset method, like this:

```
class JobAttachmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(JobAttachmentAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(spam_count__gt= 3)
```

All looks cool.

Now I can only see JobAttachment whose spam_count is greater than 3.

Now Trouble starts here:
Once i go into one of the JobAttachment's detail admin page, and change the spam_count to less than 3 and hit "Save and continue editing" it gives me a 404 page instead of continuing on same page.

(It actually says "job attachment object with primary key u'some_id' does not exist").

How can this be sorted ? 
Thanks.

Comment: It may be better to implement this with a SimpleListFilter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14569961/585783

Comment: i removed save_and_continue button.. it somehow sorted my issue.

Comment: If the error actually says some_id does not exist, you are not showing us all your code.