# Filtering the filter: limiting choices in django admin filter by user privileges

Tags: django, django-admin

OK, so I now can limit choices available in the change form as follows:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    from login.models import Room
    groups = [group.name for group in request.user.groups.all()]
    if 'principal' in groups:
        schoolname = request.user.principal.school.name
        if db_field.name == 'room':
            print("match")
            kwargs['queryset'] = Room.objects.filter(school__name=schoolname)
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

list_display = ('surname','givennames', 'room')
list_filter = ('room',)
```

That is, the above succeeds in showing the user only students enrolled in his or her school.

My trouble is that the user still sees rooms from schools they are not connected to on the list_filter, which is ignoring formfield_for_foreignkey

So instead of seeing a half dozen classrooms as choices on the filter, the pulldown shows hundreds of classrooms, for all the schools in the district. I have tried to find an answer of comparable simplicity, but nothing has presented itself. What i'd like is something like formfield_for_foreignkey to apply to my filter choices.

I want to filter the choices for the filter! Little wonder google isn't helping!

This is hard to express clearly, so I will repeat myself in the hopes that there's some clarity in my redundancy.

I am trying to filter the choices available for the user to filter on, to only those choices the user has write privileges to. I want a few choices of room on which the school principal may filter the student list; instead I get many, most of which don't apply because that principal doesn't have read or write privileges there.

The examples which I am finding that seem possibly relevant are pretty opaque to me at my level of experience.

Any simple recipes out there? Thanks!

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215751/can-i-make-list-filter-in-django-admin-to-only-show-referenced-foreignkeys) might be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make list\_filter in django admin to only show referenced ForeignKeys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215751/can-i-make-list-filter-in-django-admin-to-only-show-referenced-foreignkeys)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my complete solution;

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self,request):
        # if principal (not district user) only show students
        # whose classroom is in principal's school

        qs = super(StudentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else:
            groups = [group.name for group in request.user.groups.all()]
            if 'principal' in groups:
                school = request.user.principal.school
                return qs.filter(room__school=school)
            else:
                return qs

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        # if principal (not district administrator) 
        # limit transfer to within principal's school

        from login.models import Room
        groups = [group.name for group in request.user.groups.all()]
        if 'principal' in groups:
            schoolname = request.user.principal.school.name
            print(db_field)
            print(type(db_field))
            if db_field.name == 'room':
                print("match")
                kwargs['queryset'] = Room.objects.filter(school__name=schoolname)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)


    class CustomRoom(admin.SimpleListFilter):
        # if principal (not district user)
        # only offer filter to classrooms in principal's school  

        title = 'Classroom'
        parameter_name = 'classroom'

        def lookups(self,request,model_admin):
            from login.models import Room,School
            groups = [group.name for group in request.user.groups.all()]
            if 'principal' in groups:
                school = request.user.principal.school
                rooms = Room.objects.filter(school=school)
                return ((room.id,room.roomno) for room in rooms)
            else:
                rooms = Room.objects.all()
                return ((room.id,room.roomno) for room in rooms)

        def queryset(self,request,queryset):
            selected = self.value()

            # WAS return queryset.filter(room=selected)
            # this does not handle All case correctly 

            if selected:
                return queryset.filter(room=selected)
            else:
                 return queryset


    list_display = ('surname','givennames', 'room')
    list_filter=('enrolled',CustomRoom,)

# Register the admin class with the associated model
admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```

Quite a bit messier than I wanted, but if you think of it as three separate smallish steps it's not too terrible.