# How to filter a ForeignKey in Django Model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter a field to be shown in the Django admin form:

```
class Buy(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    buy_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'DM {self.id}'
```

```
class Sell(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Buy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'DM {self.id}'
```

The issue is: the Django admin form must show only item > 0 in the Sell model. How can I do that with ForeignKey relationship in a simple way? I tried `limit_to` but it didn't work with greater than values.

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215751/can-i-make-list-filter-in-django-admin-to-only-show-referenced-foreignkeys.

Comment: @kashyapkn I don't think so. I've already checked this topic before... But thank you anyway!