# How to filter by field of field (multi level relationship) in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

With models design like this:

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Grade(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade)
```

Since `Student` object doens't have direct relation with `School` object, How can I filter django-admin to only display students from selected `school`?

Comment: Have you seen this https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2885/ references in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102697/creating-custom-filters-for-list-filter-in-django-admin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
school_name = "your school name"
Students_in_school = Student.objects.filter(grade__school__name = school_name)
```

Comment: As a new comer, need some times to figure out what is `grade__school__name` doing. But it helps, thanks

Comment: When you have a Foreignkey in a model, Django will auto create a relation model for you. in Student model "grade" is pointing to model Grade and in side Grade "school" is pointing to model School once you call grade__school__name django will join three model for you