# Django admin display filter depending on other filters

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Here is an example of models:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    ...

class Chapter(models.Model):
    ... 
    book = models.ForeignKey('Books')

class Exercise(models.Model):
    ...
    book = models.ForeignKey('Books')
    chapter = models.ForeignKey('Chapter')
```

And here is the Admin class for exercise:

```
class ExerciseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   ...
   list_filter = (('book',admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),('chapter',admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter))

admin.site.register(Exercise, ExerciseAdmin)
```

I now have the filters `book` and `chapter` for `exercise`. When I click on a `book` in the filter `book`, it shows me all the `exercises` of the selected `book` accordingly. But in the list of filter `chapter`, it still shows all the `chapters` of all the `books`.

Is there a way to only display, in the filter `chapter`, the `chapters` of the `book` that I selected in the first filter `book`? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, but here I use the GET parameter of the url from the admin panel to get the ID of the book then I can select the corresponding chapters. And it works!

```
class ChapterFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'chapter' 
    parameter_name = 'chapter'
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        if 'book__id__exact' in request.GET:
            id = request.GET['book__id__exact']
            chapters = set([c.chapter for c in model_admin.model.objects.all().filter(book=id)])
        else:
            chapters = set([c.chapter for c in model_admin.model.objects.all()])
        return [(b.id, b.titre) for b in chapters]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(chapter__id__exact=self.value())

class ExerciseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_filter = (('book',admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter), (ChapterFilter))
```

Comment: Btw, parentheses around `(ChapterFilter)` are not needed. Don't mistake it for a tuple

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this from the admin documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter with a SimpleListFilter

example in this thread... [Creating Custom Filters for list_filter in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102697/creating-custom-filters-for-list-filter-in-django-admin)

Guessing here...

```
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class ChapterFilter(SimpleListFilter):
   title = 'chapter' 
   parameter_name = 'chapter'

   def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
       chapters = set([c.book for c in model_admin.model.objects.all()])
       return [(b.id, b.name) for b in chapters]

   def queryset(self, request, queryset):
       if self.value():
           return queryset.filter(book__id__exact=self.value())

class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (('book',admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter), (ChapterFilter))
```

Comment: Yes but I don't really see how I have to modify the lookups to do what I want

Comment: thank you but in the lookup, you're loading books and not chapters

Comment: In some way I have to get the ID of the book I selected in the filter and then use it to select all the corresponding chapter in the lookup. But still can't find how.