# Dhango 1.11 how to filter content of a filter?

Tags: django, filter, model, admin

Django 1.11 Python 3.6

I have two models, one is using a dropdown filter of the other model's list,  and it all works:

```
models.py

class Office(models.Manager):
      ...code....

class Customer(models.Manager):
      ...code....   
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, blank=False, null=False)
      ...code....
```

```
admin.py

class CustomerAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ["office", "<some_other_filter>"]
```

I get a dropdown with the list of offices on my Customer view just like I wanted, everything works.

Now for whatever reason I would like to filter the content of the "office" filter on Customer view, e.g. to remove some entries from that dropdown but only for the filter - the Office view data should stay the same, i.e. the full list. Overriding `get_queryset` in `class Office` does not do it, actually, it does the opposite of what I need - it only filters the data that gets fed to the view, but not the list of the entries in the filter. Is there clean and easy way to filter a filter in Django 1.11?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...
Here is how I got what I wanted (along the lines of [Creating Custom Filters for list_filter in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102697/creating-custom-filters-for-list-filter-in-django-admin)):

```
in admin.py
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter
class MyCustomFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = '<some title>'
    parameter_name = '<some_entity>__id__exact'
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        all_entries = model_admin.model.objects.all()
        filtered_entries = set([<bunch of code to do the filtering>])
        return set([(<dropdown_entry>.id, <dropdown_entry>.name) for entry in filtered_entries])

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(tss_id=self.value())

        return queryset.all()
```

```
in models.py
class CustomerAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin):
    # list_filter = ["office", "<some_other_filter>"]
    list_filter = [MyCustomFilter, "<some_other_filter>"]
```