# How to use a property method in list_filter in custom admin changelist?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    @property
    def is_paid(self):
        return self.apayment4thisuser.all().filter(expirydate__gt=timezone.now().date()).count()>0
```

In the customadmin I am able to add `is_paid` in `list_display`, but it is throwing error when I add it to my `list_filter`:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    list_filter = ['app_user','is_paid']
    list_display = ['id',
                    'username',
                    'email',
                    'is_paid',
                    ]
```

This is the error:

```
ERRORS:
<class 'users.admin.CustomUserAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[1]' refers to 'is_paid', which does not refer to a Field.
```

Is there not any way to add this to `list_filter`?

Comment: You'll need to create a custom filter for what you want, it should be a class inheriting from `SimpleListFilter`. There is a section in the docs about how to do it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45136544/6505847) should help

Comment: @Iain Shelvington , I tried it but it looks like that also works on the fields, it fails on property. It gives an error that  "Cannot resolve keyword 'is_paid' into field"

Comment: The filtering mechanism is happening in database level hence you can't do it on a property, unless you made an annotated field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a custom filter like this :

```
class IsPaidFilter(SimpleListFilter):

   # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
   # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.
   title = 'is paid'

   # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
   parameter_name = 'is_paid'

   def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
      return (
           ('True', True), 
           ('False', False)
             )

   def queryset(self, request, queryset): 
      if self.value():
          # If is_paid=True filter is activated
          return queryset.filter(<Write your logic here>)
      else:
          # If is_paid=True filter is activated
          return queryset.filter(<Write your other logic>)
```

And for this logic, this could be useful :

```
Q(Count(apayment4thisuser, 
      filter=Q(apayment4thisuser__expirydate__gt=timezone.now().date())))
```

Comment: caution, in my django 4.0 version, the `self.value()` in lookups, will always a str, this cause wrong judgement result. should use `if self.value() == 'True'`