# Django Admin: How to filter by custom list display field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

In the admin class, I have defined a custom list display as follows

```
list_display = ('custom_display_method_name',)
def custom_display_method_name(self, instance):
    #perform custom operation for list display which uses property of the model
```

How do I write a filter which allows filtering by the custom display, or alternatively filtering by property of a model? I have trued writing a custom filter, but it comes down to queryset. Is there a way to simply filter by the custom display that I have written?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately because of the way the list filter works, it has to be a field on the model, and can't be a read_only field added to the `ModelAdmin` or a property on the `Model`.

You can however create a custom filter, that can filter based on anything you want. This is achieved by special classes (that typically inherit from `SimpleListFilter`). There are quite a few places that give a good guide as to how to create these classes, that would be better than I can achieve here:

- [The django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)
- [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102697/creating-custom-filters-for-list-filter-in-django-admin) has quite a good example