# (Django) How to change admin site filtering panel options?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to set a filter on the **Seller** model's admin page using the **rate** field, but there's a slight issue.
the rate field can have a range of: **-1 + (0, 5]**
I want the filter panel to have **6** values, each corresponding to a rate above or equal to the corresponding number **(-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)**
at the moment it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpzmM.png), How can I achieve my goal?

models.py:

```py
class Seller(models.Model):
    """
    A model for the sellers of the Product model, connected to which with a ForeignKey
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1275, blank=False)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, validators=[validate_date_now])
    rate = models.FloatField(default=-1)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=False)
    sale_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.name)
```

admin.py:

```py
class SellerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (
                'join_date',
                'name',
                'description',
            ),

        }),
        ('Advanced information', {

            'fields': (
                'sale_count',
                'rate',
                'logo',
            )
        })
    )
    list_display = ('name', 'join_date', 'sale_count', 'rate')
    list_filter = ('join_date', 'rate')
    search_fields = ('name',)
    readonly_fields = ('join_date', 'rate', 'sale_count')
```

Comment: You need to create yor own filter like https://stackoverflow.com/a/45136544/13773284